# Convert String into binary integer, do bit manipulations and again store that binary value as String in Java

Tags: java, casting, binary, bit-manipulation

In JAVA,
I want to accept as strings, which are n bit binary code and i want to perform 'and' operation and 'or' operation on those binary codes.

How can i

i)convert string into binary (Store in integer).

ii)what are the bit manipulation methods present in the string.

iii)Again I want to store the n bit in a string.

Comment: Use `Integer.parseInt()`; it has an argument allowing you to specify the base. For bit manipulations, not in the string itself, no, but you have the classical bitwise operators defined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To parse a String containing for example `"11011"` into an `int`, use `Integer.parseInt(String s, int radix)` - in this case you want to use radix 2 (binary). For example:

```
String input = "11011";
int value = Integer.parseInt(input, 2);
```

Class `String` does not have any bit manipulation methods. When you have parsed the `String` into an `int`, you can use Java's usual bitwise operators; for example `&` for "and" and `|` for "or".

See the tutorial: [Bitwise and Bit Shift Operators](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html).

Comment: i am able to do the first two operations, but when i want to do the third operation it is printing the value rather than the binary string.

Comment: To print an `int` in binary, use `Integer.toBinaryString`, for example: `System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(value));`